# Permission issue while running Dockerfile for Fhirbase

Tags: postgresql, git, docker, dockerfile

I followed the steps provided in https://www.health-samurai.io/fhirbase website, using the Fhirbase in Docker and Download Fhirbase both are working perfectly without any issue.

Now, I want to put Fhirbase code (https://github.com/fhirbase/fhirbase?_ga=2.137200179.2086351274.1637554537-194486469.1637215452) into my private gitlab repo and I want run my gitlab fhirbase code In Docker using Dockerfile.
I have created a Dockerfile as below --

```
FROM postgres:10.5
WORKDIR /fhirbase

COPY demo/bundle.ndjson.gzip .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git

RUN git clone https://gitlab.com/username/fhirbase.git /usr/bin/fhirbase
CMD cd /usr/bin/fhirbase
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/bin/fhirbase"]
CMD make
CMD hash -r
CMD make install

RUN mkdir /pgdata && chown postgres:postgres /pgdata

USER postgres


 RUN PGDATA=/pgdata /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres  & \
    until psql -U postgres -c '\q'; do \
        >&2 echo "Postgres is starting up in first..."; \
        sleep 5; \
    done && \
    psql -U postgres -c 'create database fhirbase;' && \
    fhirbase -d fhirbase init && \
    fhirbase -d fhirbase load --mode=insert ./bundle.ndjson.gzip; \
    pg_ctl -D /pgdata stop

#EXPOSE 3000

EXPOSE 3000

CMD pg_ctl -D /pgdata start && until psql -U postgres -c '\q'; do \
        >&2 echo "Postgres is starting up..."; \
        sleep 5; \
    done && \
    exec fhirbase -d fhirbase web
```

When I run the above dockerfile getting the below error--

```
D:\FhirBase\fhirbase>docker run d6ba47544a36
waiting for server to start....2021-11-26 12:37:23.322 UTC [11] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2021-11-26 12:37:23.323 UTC [11] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2021-11-26 12:37:23.390 UTC [11] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-11-26 12:37:23.483 UTC [12] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-11-26 12:28:08 UTC
2021-11-26 12:37:23.556 UTC [11] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
/bin/sh: 1: exec: fhirbase: Permission denied
```

Please help me regarding the dockerfile.

Comment: It looks like you have `CMD` several places where you mean to have `RUN`; only the last `CMD` has an effect and all of the previous ones are ignored.  Check out the source tree anywhere besides `/usr/bin`; if `/usr/bin/fhirbase` is a directory then you'll almost always get this error (even if you `chmod +x` the directory).  You should also strongly consider running the PostgreSQL database in a separate container.

Comment: This looks quite similar to your previous [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124086/unable-to-run-fhirbase-command-in-docker). The usual process would be to edit your question to update it, rather than delete it and start over; repeatedly doing this could result in a question ban.